# $\mathcal U$ Grothendieck universe. Is $\mathcal{P(U)}$ a model for NBG?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

Suppose we are in ZFC, let $\mathcal U$ be an uncountable [Grothendieck universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe) and consider the set of its parts $\mathcal{P(U)}$. (I will index axioms as $(\mathcal U.n)$)

Note that if $x \in \mathcal U$, then $x \in\mathcal{P(U)}$, directly from $(\mathcal U.1)$ (i.e., $\mathcal U$ is a transitive set).

Further, if $x \in \mathcal{P(U)}$ and $|x|<|\mathcal U|$, then $x \in \mathcal U$. (This is not so trivial and require the axiom of choice. Actually, in ZFC, Grothendieck universes are equivalent to the so called transitive [Tarski *class*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory); a sketch of the proof, in italian, can be found [here](http://www.scienzematematiche.it/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=4296&p=21141#p21141)).

Thus, $\mathcal{P}_<(\mathcal U) := \{x \in \mathcal{P(U)}\,|\,|x|<|\mathcal U|\} = \mathcal U$.

Denoting $\mathcal P_=(\mathcal U) := \{C \in \mathcal{P(U)}\,|\,|C|=|\mathcal U|\}$, we have $\mathcal{P(U)} = \mathcal{P}_<(\mathcal U) \cup \mathcal P_=(\mathcal U) = \mathcal U \cup \mathcal P_=(\mathcal U)$, the union being disjoint.

Define the binary relation $\in_{\mathcal U} \subseteq \mathcal{P(U)}\times \mathcal{P(U)}$ such that ${\in_{\mathcal U}}_{|\mathcal U \times \mathcal{P(U)}} = {\in_{\text{ZFC}}}_{|\mathcal U \times \mathcal{P(U)}}$ and ${\in_{\mathcal U}}_{|\mathcal P_=(\mathcal U) \times \mathcal{P(U)}} = \emptyset$. That is, $\in_{\mathcal U}$ restricted to $\mathcal U \times \mathcal{P(U)}$ is just the usual set-relation $\in_{\text{ZFC}}$ of ZFC (i.e., just $\in$, if you prefer); and there is no other couple in $\in_{\mathcal U}$.

Does $(\mathcal{P(U)}, \in_{\mathcal U})$ serve as a model for [NBG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory)?

As two-sorted theory, this is equivalent to choose $\mathcal{P(U)}$ as classes,  as sets the parts $x \in \mathcal{P(U)}$ such that $x \in \mathcal U$ (i.e., the parts $x \subset U$ such that $|x| < |\mathcal U|$) and as binary relation the modified membership $\in_{\mathcal U}$ defined above.

Comment: What is $\in_{ZFC}$? Also NBG is a two-sort theory, so you need to tell us what are the sets and what are the classes of the model.

Comment: Your edit did not answer my question. What are the sets and what are the classes of your model? (Also no need to write "Edited" in your post, there is an automatic stamp telling the readers that the post had been edited.)

Comment: I really think NBG can be described as a single-sort theory. Just define a *set* to be a class $x$ for which there exists a class $C$ such that $x \in C$.

Comment: Hmm. Yes. I think that you're right. To the actual question, if $M$ is a model of ZFC, then $\text{Def}(M)$, the collection of all internally-definable classes is a model of NBG. I don't know about the full power set, though. I suppose it's a matter of verifying some axioms. Also is a Grothendieck universe a model of ZFC to begin with? (I know that some models of ZFC are Grothendieck universes)

Comment: Yes, if it is uncountable. Actually, axioms for universes are defined in such a way to allow all the usual set-theoretic operations with elements belonging to them. (It is also reported in the wiki page, as a -matter of reference). I verified the axioms on my own; but, finding nothing about on web, I have supposed I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Uhm, about the remark regarding choice... if $x\in\cal P(U)$ then $x\subseteq\cal U$ and so $|x|\leq|\cal U|$. Where do the axiom of choice comes in?

Comment: Since every $y \in x$ is still in $\mathcal U$, we need to reduce our problem to $(\mathcal U.4)$; that is, we want to find an index-set $I \in\mathcal U$ such that $|x|\leq|I|(<|\mathcal U|)$, thus a surjective function $f\colon I \to x$, in order to prove that $\bigcup_{y \in f(i)} y = x \in \mathcal U$ (indeed, by $(\mathcal U.4)$). To prove that for every cardinal $|\kappa| < |\mathcal U|$ there exists $\lambda \in \mathcal U$, $|\kappa|\leq |\lambda|$, you need AC. Actually, you are just costructing $\mathbf{Ord}_{\mathcal U}$, the ordinal numbers belonging to $\mathcal U$. Continue...

Comment: Further, since it is a theorem (see [SGA4 vol. 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9minaire_de_G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_Alg%C3%A9brique_du_Bois_Marie#SGA_4)) that a non-empty Grothendieck universe contains all of its finite subsets and a subset of each finite cardinality, one can assume that $\mathbb N \in \mathcal U$.

Comment: Sorry. I still don't see where the axiom of choice enters the game. This axiom just says that (1) No element of $\cal U$ can be mapped onto $\cal U$; (2) The range of a map from an element of $\cal U$ into $\cal U$ is an element of $\cal U$ - that is, $\cal U$ is a model of second-order replacement. What I don't see is where the axiom of choice gets into necessity here.

Comment: I don't know exactly how much AC can be _avoided_. Surely, it is essential (see [here](http://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2008-March/012783.html)). You can find a complete solution, also offered by Professor Blass, on MO ([click](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/101346/about-the-notions-of-grothendieck-universe-and-tarski-universe/101361#101361)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the power set of a Grothendieck universe is a model of NBG, and even of the stronger Morse-Kelley set theory.

Comment: I suspected this is the answer, and I was hoping that you'd turn up to give it!

Comment: Many thanks, Professor Blass. I think it is an interesting result, that makes clear the incredible expressive power of [TG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory).