# Did Grothendieck prove that Grothendieck universes are equivalent to transitive Tarski classes?

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

There is a page in [Metamath](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmtheorems83.html) ([updated link](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/df-tsk.html)) that claims the following:

> Later Grothendieck invented the concept of Grothendieck's universes
>   and showed they were equal to transitive Tarski's classes.

Transitive Tarski classes are mentioned, e.g. [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309580/mathcal-u-grothendieck-universe-is-mathcalpu-a-model-for-nbg). A Tarski class $U$ satisfies the following conditions ([given here](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2008-March/012783.html)):

1. If $A\in U$ and $B \subseteq A$, then $B \in U$;
2. If $A\in U$, then $P(A)\in U$;
3. If $A \subseteq U$, and $|A|\neq|U|$, then $A \in U$.

A transitive Tarski class additionally satisfies:

4. If $A\in U$ and $a\in A$, then $a\in U$.

Is anyone aware of the exact reference for this claim? Or, in other words: **Where can I find Grothendieck's proof?**

Comment: May you give a definition of the Tarski classes? I can't find it.

Comment: @HanulJeon I edited the original post with a definition.

Comment: A lot of his more recent work is in letters and manuscripts etc. I'm not even sure there is a complete collected works.